# Laravel Relationship Using An OR Condition on the joining field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, relationship

---

EDIT

To clarify, I am looking for a solution that will work with eager loading and be able to leverage all of the existing features of a Laravel relationship. I am aware I can use accessor attributes and other workarounds, but I cannot figure out how to do this and have it work EXACTLY like any other Laravel relationship.

---

Is there any way to create a relationship on a Laravel model using an "OR" condition for the field used to join the table while loading an eloquent model?

Example Table: `user_connections`

| Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | bigInt|primary|auto_increment |
| from_user_id | bigInt |
| to_user_id | bigInt |
| created_at | timestamp? |
| updated_at | timestamp? |

If I have a Laravel Model named `UserConnection` that uses the above table schema, is there any way to define a relationship on that model that can utilize either the `from_user_id` field *OR* the `to_user_id` field.

The goal is to have a relationship named `userConnections` on a User model that can be tied to either field.

Example of Desired Syntax:

```
class User {
...

// THE RELATIONSHIP METHOD NAME TO USE (DOESN'T HAVE TO BE `hasMany`)
public function userConnections(){
    return $this->hasMany(
        \App\Models\UserConnection::class, /* THE TARGET CLASS TO BE LOADED */
        'from_user_id||to_user_id',        /* JOIN ON EITHER OF THESE FIELDS */
        'id'                               /* THE ID OF THE USER IN THIS MODEL */
    );
}
```

I know I can do this with a query and load the models manually. But I want to stick to the Laravel format for relationships so that other people on this project can use the relationship naturally.

Please don't bother responding if your answer is going to be **"Don't structure the database that way"**, because I cannot change the schema. I need to figure out how to make it work with this schema.

My concept isn't set in stone like the schema is, but it should illustrate what I'm trying to achieve. I am entirely open minded to any solution that works with this db schema.

Hoping someone else has run into a similar issue and might have a solution.

Thanks in advance to anyone who has read this far.

Comment: which field do you want to check first?

Comment: @krisgjika I want the query to match on either field. Doesnt matter which one it matches on first because the query will need to match on both.

Comment: why not load both relations and join them in memory via an attribute? given UserConnections is a pivot I don't see another way

Comment: @krisgjika because accessor attributes (like getUserConnectionAttribute) cannot be eager loaded. The goal is to figure out a way to make a relationship work with all of laravels features, not just work under limited conditions. Also UserConnections is not a pivot. There is no table that the user model is trying to obtain via the user_connections.. It's surprisingly dificult to do something that seems so simple. I appreciate your thoughts though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure. Is this what you were asking for?

```
UserConnection::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('from_user_id', $this->id)
          ->orWhere('to_user_id', $this->id);
});
```

---

You can combine it with Laravel Attribute for a single call.

```
public function userConnectionsQuery()
{
    return UserConnection::where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('from_user_id', $this->id)
              ->orWhere('to_user_id', $this->id);
    });
}

public function getUserConnectionsAttribute()
{
    return $this->userConnectionsQuery()->get();
}
```

This will work like this

```
$user = User::find($userId);

$userConnections = $user->userConnectionsQuery()->get(); # Directly call
$userConnections = $user->userConnectionsQuery()->where('created_at', '>', $someDate)->get(); # Directly call
$userConnections = $user->userConnections; # Dynamic Access
```

Comment: I did use the $this->id method like you described prior to posting this question... but it doesnt work with eager loading... EX: \App\Models\User::with('userConnections')->get().... That approach only works when the model and data are already loaded. Im looking for a solution that works with all laravel syntax natively.

Comment: @dvicemuse what you mean by  *laravel syntax natively.*, write here what's in your mind.

Comment: by "Natively" I mean, all eloquent query builders should work just like any other relationship. Any standard relationship in Laravel allows for eager loading and nested relationship queries... Yes, your solution will work but only 50% of the time. It will never work when using ->with() or ->whereHas() because the data attributes for individual models arent loaded until after the query is completed.

Comment: I think your edited response is very creative. I never considered faking the relationship as an accessor attribute and a separate query... That is extremely close to what I'm trying to do, but it is still syntactically wrong and won't work with eager loading. You have given me some ideas I hadn't considered though. If I build off of your method and figure it out with some php magic method overrides, I'll come back and mark your answer as accepted. I sincerely appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function connections()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserConnection::class, function ($query) {
        $query->where('from_user_id', $this->id)
              ->orWhere('to_user_id', $this->id);
    });
}
```

Comment: In Laravel, when you want to define a relationship with an OR condition on the joining field, you typically use a closure inside the relationship definition. Here's how you can modify your userConnections() method to achieve this:

Comment: Unfortunately this approach will not work with eager loading. It works great if a model and data is already loaded, but will not work with the ->with() syntax or the ->has() syntax. Appreciate the answer though